# how to get data as grouped rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

hello and sorry of my bad English words .

i need help in mysql query

I have table named mytable include the following columns

1. column for id (auto increment).
2. column for time (in timestamp).
3. column for data.

I need to get data grouped by days and each day with it's data but 
the data for each day must not exceeds 3 rows and counts of remains 
rows for each day, and the all count of groups must not exceeds 9 groups as limit

```
(mytable)
id | time      | data
----------------------
1 | 1366553067 | data1
2 | 1366546958 | data2
3 | 1366546951 | data3
4 | 1366546953 | data4
5 | 1366546931 | data5
6 | 1366545926 | data6
7 | 1366564550 | data7
8 | 1366548683 | data8
----------------------
```

- Note : // the time stamp in the top is not correct.

i need the result look like this table.

```
(the result table)
time              | data  | count of remains row
-----------------------------------------------
april 12 2013     | data1 | 3
april 12 2013     | data2 | 3 // group one 
april 12 2013     | data3 | 3

april 13 2013     | data7 | 0 // group two 

april 14 2013     | data8 | 0 // group three 
------------------------------------------------
```

what should i write in query !?

I will be very happy for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "and the all count of groups must not exceeds 9 groups as limit"? What happens if on April 12 2013 there are 10 records, or 12 records. What happens if there are 7 remaining rows on April 13?. I would also suggest to rewrite the whole paragraph as several sentences. And replace the timestamps with dates.

Comment: Why, why, why-oh-***why*** are you storing timestamps as integers and not as... ooooh... say, [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html)?

Comment: i mean i need to display only the last 9 days, my program logic need that.

Comment: have you tried the answer I provided?

Answer (score 0):

The following query (untested) provides a result like the output example:

```
SELECT time, data, IF(totalrows.total > 3, totalrows.total - 3, 0) AS remains
FROM (SELECT numbered.*
     FROM    SELECT ordered.*,
                 IF (id = @prev,
                     @n := @n + 1,
                     @n := 1 AND @prev := id) as position
            FROM (SELECT mytable.* ORDER BY time) AS ordered
            JOIN (SELECT @n := 0, @prev := id) AS setup)
            AS   numbered
     WHERE  numbered.position < 4)
     AS     top3
INNER JOIN (SELECT time, count(*) as total FROM mytable GROUP BY time) AS totalrows
ON top3.time = totalrows.time
```

Comment: Your answer seems great, but i can't understand it because i beginner in SQL

Comment: My code is big in actual, so when i apply your answer in my code i get many errors.

Comment: I've been offline, let me know if you still need help and what is the error.